# Receive same socket event in two useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io, nodes

I want to access same event in two different useEffect in same page. I have tried doing this but its doesn't work Here is what I did. I just want to know if this possible to recieve same event in same page in two diffrent useEffect. Because in the first useEffect I am getting the data but not in the second. Or is there in trick which I can apply.

```
FIRST useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
socket.on('event', () => {
  console.log('WORK');
});

return () => {
  socket.off('event');
};
 }, []);

Second useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
socket.on('event', () => {
  console.log('NOT COMMING HERE');
});

return () => {
  socket.off('event');
};
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I do not see a use case where you would need to register two listeners for the same event in the same running (The docs also kinda hint that every event should have one listener). The best solution that seems reasonable to me Is to use some sort of conditional logic to decide on the code that will be run in the listener.

2 tweaks that I would not usually recommend:

1. Would be to emit a new event in your listener to the server and resend it to your frontend code but with a different event name and then have the listener for the new event in the second useEffect.
2. Update a state variable in the event listener that would make the second useEffect run

Comment: There is a different state I need to manage that's why I need to use two useEffect and I totally agree with the tweaks that you said. I will use all things in a single event because I need to manage the state of the listener.